# Why circles are not created if small?

Tags: 3dsmax

I have changed the scale in 3DSMax to my own and now I can't create any object, including circle, if it is of the size which is normal for my scale. Instead, I have to create big object first and then modify it to a smaller size. It looks like there is a minimal size protection is set somewhere - where is the setting for it?

**UPDATE**

While creating a circle, if I drag for 0.04m circle disappears after drag end. If I drag for 0.08m circle also disappears. If I drag for more than 0.1m, circle persists after drag end.

How can I set it so that it persist after 0.01m too?

Comment: You should tell us which part of the code is giving you this problem or what you are trying to do because, without that, it is almost impossible to tell you what is wrong with it. But maybe it is because you don't quite understand the scaling. Please give us more details before you expect an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because the camera that renders your editor window has a near and far range that it uses to display the circles (spheres?) called the clipping plane. It's a good idea to get in the habit of working in a real unit system like meters, inches 3dsmax has always had the issue of working at small scales. If you select the object and retarget it with the camera, it may adjust the clipping plane to make the object visible. So if your sphere is a basketball, make it the actual size of a basketball given the units you are working in.

Comment: I have encountered this in 3ds max as well - it's not a case of the object not being visible. If the object is too small when you click to confirm creation, it will not be created. I don't think you can adjust this threshold anywhere, just scale up your unit system to something reasonable and you shouldn't encounter this quirk.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your unit setup.

If you require centimeter accuracy, set your system units to centimeters (and your display units to meters if you like).

You will then have no problem creating circle shapes of centimeter (or even millimeter) radius.

Alternatively, use the keyboard creation tool instead of clicking and dragging, and you should be able to create the circle as well.

At some point you may also want or need to increase the precision of displayed values, in the preferences the default is 3 decimal places.

Comment: Thanks! But where to set this? I set `Meters` in `Units Setup` dialog and "1 Unit = 1,0 Centimeters" in `System Unit Setup` dialog, but still can't create small circles.

Comment: Using 1.0 cm system unit scale and 1 m display units, the smallest circle I can create by dragging is of 0.001 m radius.

Comment: I don't have a value in display unit setup, only "flavor", like "meters", "centimeters" and so on, without setting how many of these units. May be I am looking into different place?

Comment: no. you are looking at the right settings.

Comment: Hence the reason is different.

Comment: As I said in my answer...try the keyboard creation tool

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I found out how to solve the thing. Its again a 3ds Max bug. Whec creating circles just change the Creation Method from Center to Edge, make one and than again change it to Center. That worked for me :)[image]